# How to partition free space in a Mac SSD

Tags: partition, macos

I have a Mac with a 250Go SSD. I used to have a Windows partition, but as I had no longer any use for it I wanted to free up its space.

My error was here : instead of using BootCamp helper to delete my Windows partition, I deleted the space in the Disk Utility app.

Now, I am in this situation when I open my Disk Utility:

[image]

So there are clearly 2 free spaces of 30Go each on the drive (which is weird since it says there are 251Go total, and if we sum up the 3 spaces here it gives something like 280 Go). Then I tried to partition the space like this :

[image]

Which gives me the following error:

[image]

Sorry for the French, basically it says that the starting util of the volumes I wanted to free up are mounted. So I went and tried with my terminal to find those spaces, but they are nowhere to be found :

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            219.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +219.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 BB809D5E-5AC1-490E-8037-651B300154BD
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +7.5 GB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS InstallESD              7.2 GB     disk3s2
```

Since I can't find the volumes in my diskutil list, I can't force the unmount on them. How to retrieve this space ?

Comment: Thanks for asking. No worries on translation or some foreign words. The English is very adequate for starting an answer. To paraphrase, you want to grow disk0s2 from 219 to 250 GB, correct? Pretty sure you can live resize this, but wanted to measure twice before executing a command...

Answer (score 1):

Do you have something like in the screenshot in your Disk Utility app?
[image: Container in Disk Utility]